# Xamarin IOS random crashing on UI change

Tags: xamarin.ios

We have an iPad app build with Xamarin.iOS that has started to crash randomly for our customers.

This occurs when users interact with the UI but appears to happen randomly, as they can work fine for hours then, all of a sudden they click on something and the app crashes.

All attempts to replicate locally have failed (both on simulator and on physical devices) but the number of users reporting this has increased, as well as the number of crashes logged in App Center.

Any help/insight into the below call stack would be greatly appreciated.

```
Exception Type:  SIGABRT
Exception Codes: #0 at 0x1bc0febbc
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x00000001bc0febbc __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib                    0x000000018cc336ac abort + 120
2   MyApp    0x0000000112a1bf40 xamarin_unhandled_exception_handler (runtime.m:1109)
3   MyApp    0x00000001128c1bbc mono_invoke_unhandled_exception_hook (exception.c:1265)
4   MyApp    0x0000000112856d28 mono_handle_exception_internal (mini-exceptions.c:2782)
5   MyApp    0x00000001128556fc mono_handle_exception (mini-exceptions.c:3107)
6   MyApp    0x000000011284b3fc mono_arm_throw_exception (exceptions-arm64.c:401)
7   MyApp    0x0000000101371fbc throw_exception + 168
8   MyApp    0x00000001010d613c System_Runtime_ExceptionServices_ExceptionDispatchInfo_Throw + 40
9   MyApp    0x00000001010dc424 System_Runtime_CompilerServices_AsyncMethodBuilderCore__c__ThrowAsyncb__7_0_object + 80
10  MyApp    0x0000000101da69cc Foundation_NSAsyncSynchronizationContextDispatcher_Apply (NSAction.cs:178)
11  MyApp    0x000000010132d8c0 wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr + 268
12  MyApp    0x0000000112868a94 mono_jit_runtime_invoke (mini-runtime.c:3190)
13  MyApp    0x00000001129226c4 mono_runtime_invoke_checked (object.c:3052)
14  MyApp    0x0000000112925f04 mono_runtime_invoke (object.c:3107)
15  MyApp    0x0000000100f09230 native_to_managed_trampoline_7(objc_object*, objc_selector*, _MonoMethod**, unsigned int) (registrar.m:424)
16  MyApp    0x0000000100f09764 -[__MonoMac_NSAsyncSynchronizationContextDispatcher xamarinApplySelector] (registrar.m:6646)
17  Foundation                           0x0000000183c066a0 __NSThreadPerformPerform + 160
18  CoreFoundation                       0x000000018256a4fc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 20
19  CoreFoundation                       0x000000018257a62c __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 200
20  CoreFoundation                       0x00000001824bc834 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 252
21  CoreFoundation                       0x00000001824c1f08 __CFRunLoopRun + 764
22  CoreFoundation                       0x00000001824d5250 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 568
23  GraphicsServices                     0x00000001a2e20988 GSEventRunModal + 156
24  UIKitCore                            0x0000000184cd5a94 -[UIApplication _run] + 1076
25  UIKitCore                            0x0000000184a6efd4 UIApplicationMain + 332
26  MyApp    0x0000000101e50c38 wrapper_managed_to_native_UIKit_UIApplication_UIApplicationMain_int_string___intptr_intptr + 340
27  MyApp    0x0000000101dcf3f0 UIKit_UIApplication_Main_string___string_string (UIApplication.cs:75)
28  MyApp    0x0000000100f4b9e0 MyApp_Main_string__ (Main.cs:19)
29  MyApp    0x000000010132d8c0 wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr + 268
30  MyApp    0x0000000112868a94 mono_jit_runtime_invoke (mini-runtime.c:3190)
31  MyApp    0x00000001129226c4 mono_runtime_invoke_checked (object.c:3052)
32  MyApp    0x00000001129289cc mono_runtime_exec_main_checked (object.c:0)
33  MyApp    0x0000000112846e04 mono_jit_exec (driver.c:1383)
34  MyApp    0x0000000112a2e4ac xamarin_main (monotouch-main.m:494)
35  MyApp    0x0000000100f4917c main (main.m:298)
36  ???                                  0x0000000113f244d0 0x0 + 0

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x00000001bc0f9484 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   MyApp    0x00000001129c58ec thread_func (mono-os-mutex.h:219)
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001dc7ae348 _pthread_start + 112
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001dc7ac948 thread_start + 4

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x00000001bc0f8ae8 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1   MyApp    0x000000011297021c start_wrapper_internal (threads.c:1233)
2   MyApp    0x00000001129700a0 start_wrapper (threads.c:1308)
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001dc7ae348 _pthread_start + 112
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001dc7ac948 thread_start + 4

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x00000001bc0f8aac mach_msg_trap + 8
1   CoreFoundation                       0x00000001824bdd88 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 364
2   CoreFoundation                       0x00000001824c2090 __CFRunLoopRun + 1156
3   CoreFoundation                       0x00000001824d5250 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 568
4   Foundation                           0x0000000183be2eec -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 228
5   Foundation                           0x0000000183c22000 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 84
6   UIKitCore                            0x0000000184c54f00 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 508
7   Foundation                           0x0000000183c2fbfc __NSThread__start__ + 788
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001dc7ae348 _pthread_start + 112
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001dc7ac948 thread_start + 4

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x00000001bc0f9484 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   MyApp    0x00000001129d4e68 mono_os_cond_timedwait (mono-os-mutex.c:75)
2   MyApp    0x000000011297b944 mono_w32handle_timedwait_signal_handle (mono-coop-mutex.h:103)
3   MyApp    0x000000011297b81c mono_w32handle_wait_one (w32handle.c:0)
4   MyApp    0x000000011297ba40 mono_w32handle_wait_multiple (w32handle.c:1002)
5   MyApp    0x000000011296a748 ves_icall_System_Threading_WaitHandle_Wait_internal (threads.c:2314)
6   MyApp    0x00000001128e66e8 ves_icall_System_Threading_WaitHandle_Wait_internal_raw (icall-def.h:1100)
7   MyApp    0x000000010105efb8 wrapper_managed_to_native_System_Threading_WaitHandle_Wait_internal_intptr__int_bool_int + 116
8   MyApp    0x000000010105eb18 System_Threading_WaitHandle_WaitOneNative_System_Runtime_InteropServices_SafeHandle_uint_bool_bool + 260
9   MyApp    0x000000010105e56c System_Threading_WaitHandle_InternalWaitOne_System_Runtime_InteropServices_SafeHandle_long_bool_bool + 56
10  MyApp    0x000000010105e51c System_Threading_WaitHandle_WaitOne_long_bool + 56
11  MyApp    0x000000010105e41c System_Threading_WaitHandle_WaitOne_int_bool + 56
12  MyApp    0x000000010105e4cc System_Threading_WaitHandle_WaitOne_int + 40
13  MyApp    0x00000001010629f8 System_Threading_Timer_Scheduler_SchedulerThread + 212
14  MyApp    0x0000000101057124 System_Threading_ThreadHelper_ThreadStart + 112
15  MyApp    0x000000010132d8c0 wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr + 268
16  MyApp    0x0000000112868a94 mono_jit_runtime_invoke (mini-runtime.c:3190)
17  MyApp    0x00000001129226c4 mono_runtime_invoke_checked (object.c:3052)
18  MyApp    0x0000000112928060 mono_runtime_delegate_try_invoke (object.c:4438)
19  MyApp    0x0000000112970314 start_wrapper_internal (threads.c:1255)
20  MyApp    0x00000001129700a0 start_wrapper (threads.c:1308)
21  libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001dc7ae348 _pthread_start + 112
22  libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001dc7ac948 thread_start + 4

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x00000001bc0f96b0 __select + 8
1   MyApp    0x00000001129617a8 poll_event_wait (threadpool-io-poll.c:153)
2   MyApp    0x000000011296121c selector_thread (threadpool-io.c:460)
3   MyApp    0x000000011297021c start_wrapper_internal (threads.c:1233)
4   MyApp    0x00000001129700a0 start_wrapper (threads.c:1308)
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001dc7ae348 _pthread_start + 112
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001dc7ac948 thread_start + 4

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x00000001bc0f8aac mach_msg_trap + 8
1   CoreFoundation                       0x00000001824bdd88 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 364
2   CoreFoundation                       0x00000001824c2090 __CFRunLoopRun + 1156
3   CoreFoundation                       0x00000001824d5250 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 568
4   CFNetwork                            0x0000000182edaaa8 _CFURLStorageSessionDisableCache + 50416
5   Foundation                           0x0000000183c2fbfc __NSThread__start__ + 788
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001dc7ae348 _pthread_start + 112
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001dc7ac948 thread_start + 4
=
```

We have build this app with the following version of Xamarin.iOS

```
Xamarin.iOS
Version: 15.10.0.5 
Hash: 96b3edb6d
Branch: d17-2
Build date: 2022-05-18 07:32:07-0400
```

Comment: AppCenter is not giving you a managed stack trace?

Comment: I should have stated that this is the raw stack trace from AppCenter